# Attached Property for Binding to WebBrowser not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, webbrowser-control

I have been looking for a way to get the HTML out of a WPF WebBrowser control. The two best options I have found are to bind a customer attached property to the property in the application or to build a new control from the WebBrowser control.  Considering my level of knowledge and the fact that (as of now I really only need this one time) I chose the first.  I even considered breaking MVVM style and using code-behind but I decided not to give up in the binding.

I found several examples on creating the attached property, I finally chose this one, from here [Here](http://www.michelvandervlugt.net/wpf-document-binding-with-webbrowser-control/):

```
namespace CumminsInvoiceTool.HelperClasses
{
    public static class WebBrowserExtentions
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Document", typeof(string), typeof(WebBrowserExtentions), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, DocumentPropertyChanged));

        public static string GetDocument(DependencyObject element)
        {
            return (string)element.GetValue(DocumentProperty);
        }

        public static void SetDocument(DependencyObject element, string value)
        {
            element.SetValue(DocumentProperty, value);
        }

        public static void DocumentPropertyChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser browser = target as WebBrowser;
            if (browser != null)
            {
                string document = e.NewValue as string;
                browser.NavigateToString(document);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also added the following to the xaml for the WebBrowser control (I have tried both with and without the "Path=" in the xaml:

```
<WebBrowser local:WebBrowserExtentions.Document="{Binding Path=PageCode}" Source="https://www.cummins-distributors.com/"/>
```

My View has a tab control one tab has the WebBrowser control and another tab has a textbox. When I click the get code the viewModel runs a function to set property bound to the textbox to the string the attached property of the WebBrowser is bound to.  Below is the code of my ViewModel.

```
namespace CumminsInvoiceTool.ViewModels
{
    class ShellViewModel : Screen
    {

        private string _browserContent;

        public string BrowserContent
        {
            get { return _browserContent; }
            set {
                _browserContent = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => BrowserContent);
            }
        }

        private string _pageCode;

        public string PageCode
        {
            get { return _pageCode; }
            set {
                _pageCode = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PageCode);
            }
        }


        public void StartProgressCommand()
        {

        }

        public void GetContent()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PageCode))
            {
                BrowserContent = PageCode;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is no cintent to show", "No content Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

The application compiles and runs but when I click "Get Code" I am getting the messagebox for "PageCode" is empty.

When I set a break point at the beginning of the function for the button, the PageCode string is showing "null".

Is this an issue because I am using Caliburn.Micro or am I missing something else?

------- EDIT for comments ----------

The button calls GetContent() in the "ShellViewModel" code above.  I know the button is bound and working because the app is showing the custom messagebox I have set up to let me know when "pageCode" is null or empty.

The textbox looks like:

```
<TextBox x:Name="BrowserContent"/>
```

Comment: What does it mean when you "click Get Code"? Is that a Button? What does the Click handler look like? How is the TextBox bound to your view model? Please show a minimal, but complete and verifiable example.

Comment: I adjusted the post for your question, I am using Caliburn.Micro so the x:Name will bind to the appropriately named item in the viewmodel. Thank You

Comment: So how is that TextBox supposed to set the PageCode property?

Comment: I changed TextBox to TextBlock.  The flow I am expecting is.  The page loads, the attached property "WebBrowserExtensions" sends the page content to "PageCode" in the ViewModel through "local:WebBrowserExtentions.Document="{Binding Path=PageCode}".  When the button get code is clicked, the method "GetContent()" checks if "PageCode" is empty, if it is not, then it sets BrowserContent to PageCode.  BrowserContent should be bound to the tetbox/textblock.  The textblock is not intended to change anything, just display the string for now.

Comment: Well, the attached property does exactly the opposite. It navigates to a page when the binding source property, i.e. PageCode changes (that's what the code in the DocumentPropertyChanged method does). Instead of an attached property, you should simply attach a handler method for the WebBrowser's Navigated event.

Comment: Thank you!! I am going to start doing more research on that!